# convert from 'to_julian_date()' to 'np.datetime64'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

consider array below

```
dt = DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-01-21', '2016-01-21'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'date', freq=None)
```

i convert the above `to_julian_date()`dtype

```
j = dt.to_julian_date()
Float64Index([2457388.5, 2457388.5, 2457408.5, 2457408.5], dtype='float64')
```

how can I convert `j`back to `dt`

I tried

```
dt = pd.to_datetime(j, errors = 'coerce')
```

it converts `j` back to datetime object, but the values are not the same, here is the output

```
DatetimeIndex(['1970-01-01 00:00:00.002457388',
           '1970-01-01 00:00:00.002457388',
           '1970-01-01 00:00:00.002457408',
           '1970-01-01 00:00:00.002457408'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Julian dates](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/JulianDate.php) are number of days from a long time ago.  A time prior to the pandas Timestamp epoch.  We refer to the beginning of when a system of tracking time begins tracking time.  For `Timestamp` that is '1970-01-01'.  What I do is get the `Timestamp` epoch with `pd.to_datetime(0, unit='s')`.  That is the first possible `pandas.Timestamp`.  Then I assign the number of days of that `Timestamp` from the beginning of the Julian Date by running `to_julian_date()` on that `Timestamp`.  Now that I have the number of days from the beginning of the Julian start date to the `Timestamp` epoch, I subtract that from each of the Julian dates in `j` and that becomes the number of days from the `Timestamp` epoch (or `'1970-01-01'`).  I can then use `pd.to_datetime(j - epoch, unit='D')` to give me the `Timestamps` where each of my values represent the number of days from the `Timestamp` epoch.

I hope that is clear ;-)

first find the `julian_date` for the `pd.Timestamp` epoch

```
epoch = pd.to_datetime(0, unit='s').to_julian_date()
```

then conversion is done with `pd.to_datetime` using the parameter `unit='D'`

```
pd.to_datetime(j - epoch, unit='D')

DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-01-21', '2016-01-21'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: works perfect! can you please explain a bit on what exactly is happening here. I still did not understand the logic of epoch